# Providing legend for pre-rasterized data

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a plot containing several million data points (real-time sensor, 50 samples/s, multiple channels, 5 hours).  To keep the file size of my document down, I made a bare PNG with the line graph in MATLAB and am using `\addplot graphics` in pgfplots to add the axis lines and labels consistent with my document formatting and other pgfplots graphics.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[xmax=330, xtick={0,60,...,330}, xlabel={Time (min)}, ylabel=g, enlargelimits=false, axis on top]
         \addplot graphics [xmin=0, xmax=330, ymin=-200, ymax=800] {from_matlab.png};
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It works pretty well

[image: plot, which needs a legend]

Now I'd like to add a legend.  I'd rather create it using tikz and pgfplots, to keep consistent formatting and also have it in my document as searchable text data.

How can I let pgfplots know that this axis which contains just a single object actually needs three entries, and that these are line series of specific colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pgfplots manual mentions `\addlegendimage` which provides direct control over the styling of a subsequent legend entry.  The options aren't documented well, but testing shows that a color is accepted, and the legend style defaults to a lineseries.

```
 \addlegendimage{blue} \addlegendentry{Load Cell \#2};
 \addlegendimage{green!60!black} \addlegendentry{Load Cell \#3};
 \addlegendimage{red} \addlegendentry{Load Cell \#4};
```

This code goes *above* the `\addplot graphics`, because there is no legend entry to be paired with the graphics element itself.  To set up the legend after adding the graphics, one should supply `forget plot` as an option on `\addplot` (not on `graphics`!), causing the legend not to include an entry corresponding to the graphic, and styled as a black line .

Comment: Now is this some addition to your question or do you have found the answer in the same minute you posted the question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I didn't find this on Tex.SE yet, and in the process of researching and writing the question I found something that works.  I would welcome and accept a more complete answer.